# Bypass Verification for personal youtube api usage

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I am tying to use YouTube's api to upload videos to YouTube (for my personal usage), it works fine on testing (it's locked in private) but is there a way for me so that I can bypass the verification as I don't think it's necessary for personal usage

Comment: Is there a way to make the videos uploaded through API public?

Comment: I don't know. Also, check this out https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2963